# Why does my SQL query return two different results?

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I'm using SQL in MS Access to retrieve data from a table but depending on whether I run a query or use VBA, I get two different results for the same query.

Quite simply, I want the max value from a single column in a table. The trouble is, I think, is that the column datatype is text? The table consists, primarily, of 6 digit numbers interspersed with other formats such as 'xx-xxxxx'.

Firstly, I need to be able to do this in VBA, so I have this:

```
Private Function Create() As String

Dim rs As New ADODB.Recordset
Dim cn As New ADODB.Connection
Dim strSQL As String

Set cn = CurrentProject.Connection
cn.CursorLocation = adUseClient

strSQL = "SELECT Max(par.PN) AS PN FROM par WHERE ((PN Between CLng('100000') And CLng('999999')) And (PN Not Like '##-#####'));"

Set rs = cn.Execute(strSQL)

If (rs.RecordCount > 0) Then
    'Create = rs("PN")
    Debug.Print rs("PN")
End If

End Function
```

The result is 10-0000 so my first though is that the query is wrong so I head off over to the query builder and enter:

```
SELECT Max(par.PN) AS PN   
FROM par 
WHERE ((PN Between CLng('100000') And CLng('999999')) And (PN Not Like '##-#####'));
```

which returns 745864 when I run it. So from this I can see there is something awry here.

Now, the other thing that strikes me is that I don't think I should need `And (PN Not Like '##-#####')` in order to get a six digit number as I would have though `WHERE ((PN Between CLng('100000') And CLng('999999'))` would have been sufficient...

I have a suspicion that this is because the numbers are stored as text and because of this the between function will not work on text - if this is indeed true, I would have further expected that the CLng function would have converted successfully to number in order for this query to work.

In any case, I need to be able to get the latest six digit number using vba. Can anyone shed any light on where the problem lies?

Thanks

Comment: order of numbers as int : 1,2,3,4,5,10,111,123,345,4000, etc.   Order of numbers as text: 1,10,11,111,2,23,3,4,5,8,89, etc.   max and numbers stored as text doesn't work well...access knows this but likes doing the wrong thing anyway.  Convert to int then find max

Comment: Not sure, but might the wildcard char be different between the query builder and ADODB? I think you might  have to use underscore, or else try ` NOT LIKE '%-%' ` which will remove anything with dashes in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ADO SQL uses the ANSI 92 version of the LIKE operator (allowed wildcards: `_` for a single character, `%` for multiple characters).

MS Access and DAO use a different form of LIKE operator (see [this MSDN page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb208897%28v=office.12%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) for the allowed wildcards)

If you want to use such a comparison, I recommend you switch to DAO (if you don't have a specific reason to use ADO)

An alternative approach (and the one that would have my preference) would be casting PN to an actual number:

```sql
SELECT Max(CLng(Replace(par.PN, "-", ""))) AS PN 
FROM par 
WHERE CLng(Replace(par.PN, "-", "")) Between 100000 And 999999
```

Comment: Just tried this in both VBA (using DAO) and the query editor and both give a `Data type mismatch in criteria expression` error.  
Not sure which part is the wrong data type :0

Comment: Probably the `Between` part, you can go back to your `CLng('100000')` etc.